# Offline SQL Server database sync to online SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, offline

I have one store and planning to open another store. Currently,my store was working on local database. But now, I'm thinking to web host my local database. but the problem of online database if there will be offline due to ISP service update or router problem disconnection, my sales will be affected.

1. I'm planning to have two database if the internet is not connected it will switch to offline and sync when connected
2. If number 1 is possible then second problem is how about the transaction ID it will auto generated. if store A make 10 transaction during the store B offline then max ID is 10. Store B make 5 transaction and offline database max id was 5...when offline database sync to online then error like the transaction ID already exist due to it is primary key.

I have seen a company accomplish this task they so called "desktop server" or "front server". to hold the data until the POS get online.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this, and this question is too broad. You will need to research the pros and cons of each approach your self unfortunately

Comment: Two ways to make a unique primary key: 1. Use a GUID - but that's lazy; 2. Simply define a composite primary key consisting of the local primary key + the store key

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thank you.

Comment: @TheGeneral Actually I have been browsing regarding this matter two day. But I don't know what exactly the jargon term is.can you provide some example?so I can check it out?

Comment: There are database synchronisation tools, there are offline synchronisation technologies, there are adhock table and query approaches. this is all way too broad for stackoverlow

Comment: @TheGeneral thanks alot for giving such information.

Comment: For starters... what is the purpose of the online database? Backup? Reporting? Both? How up to date does it need to be? Daily? Hourly? Minute? Perhaps this a good starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, have and incremental ID for your online database, then as secondary column use store_id. To avoid data loss, have local database sync cached data, then even if there connection error data will be synced sooner or later. Why should your sales be hindered if online database has lost connection, not sure what data do you want to get from shared database.